# Strange behavior with stored procedure - WHERE statement is being ignored

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that selects all rows from my database where a certain column `(EventId) = x`. This works fine when I use it with my GridView in Visual Studio. Then I added a search feature to my GridView, which also searches fine.

However with the added search feature, my stored procedure does not select based on `EventId = x`. Instead it displays ALL rows, despite the id. Why? What needs to be changed? For example, if `EventId = 80`, it still will display `EventId = 7`9 and `78` etc.

Code WITHOUT search that works!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllRegistrantRapidResponse]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

        @EventId int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT *
    FROM Registrant
    WHERE EventId = @EventId
    END
```

Code WITH search that doesn't work!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllRegistrantRapidResponse]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

        @EventId int,
        @CompletedByFirstName nvarchar(20),
        @CompletedByLastName nvarchar(25),
        @FirstName nvarchar(20),
        @LastName nvarchar(25),
        @PaymentMethod nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT *
    FROM Registrant
    WHERE EventId = @EventId AND
        CompletedByFirstName LIKE '%' + @CompletedByFirstName + '%'
        OR CompletedByLastName LIKE '%' + @CompletedByLastName + '%'
        OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'
        OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'
        OR PaymentMethod LIKE '%' + @PaymentMethod + '%'
    END
```

Comment: Is one of the values you are passing in NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `and` operator has higher [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) than the `or` operator so you need parentheses, otherwise the event id check only applies to the first `like` comparison:

```
WHERE EventId = @EventId AND (
    CompletedByFirstName LIKE '%' + @CompletedByFirstName + '%'
    OR CompletedByLastName LIKE '%' + @CompletedByLastName + '%'
    OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'
    OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'
    OR PaymentMethod LIKE '%' + @PaymentMethod + '%'
  )
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Please qualify your conditions; AND conditions take precedence here

```
 SELECT *
FROM Registrant
WHERE EventId = @EventId AND
    (CompletedByFirstName LIKE '%' + @CompletedByFirstName + '%'
    OR CompletedByLastName LIKE '%' + @CompletedByLastName + '%'
    OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'
    OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'
    OR PaymentMethod LIKE '%' + @PaymentMethod + '%')
END
```

Comment: Actually it's the `and` operator that takes precedence over the `or` operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try something like:

```
WHERE EventId = @EventId AND
        (CompletedByFirstName LIKE '%' + @CompletedByFirstName + '%'
        OR CompletedByLastName LIKE '%' + @CompletedByLastName + '%'
        OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'
        OR LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'
        OR PaymentMethod LIKE '%' + @PaymentMethod + '%')
```

When you combine `AND`and `OR` you should use parentheses.